# Handle ul menu with angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on angular 7 project and have ul list which is populated dynamically from server side.

I got the items no problem my problem is I need to close the ul item and reopen it after 4 li item.

How can I make that in angular using the next example?

```
<ul class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6 list-unstyled">

  <li *ngFor="let footerPage of footerExtraPages; let i = index+1"><a routerLink="page/{{footerPage.id}}/{{footerPage.slug}}">{{footerPage.title}}</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Use your component (i.e.the TypeScript code) to split the array in slices of 4 elements. Use two nested ngFor in the view to display each slice, and each element of each slide. Don't try to do everything in the view: components exist for a reason.

Comment: Yes man this works for me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the component you have to split the original array to multiples arrays
like this example

```
    while (this.footerPages.length > 0){
      this.footerExtraPages.push(this.footerPages.splice(0, 4));
    }
```

Then you can easily display it in the html template

```
<ul *ngFor="let footerPages of footerExtraPages;let i = index" class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6 list-unstyled">
    <li *ngFor="let footerPage of footerPages;let i = index"  >
      <a routerLink="page/{{footerPage.id}}/{{footerPage.slug}}">{{footerPage.title}}</a>  
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a few ways to go about it

One would be to write a getter in order to get the elements:

html

```
  <li *ngFor="let footerPage of getFirstFour()">
    <a routerLink="page/{{footerPage.id}}/{{footerPage.slug}}"> 
      {{footerPage.title}}
    </a>
  </li>
```

ts

```
public function getFirstFour() {
  return this.footerExtraPages.map((item, i) => {
    if (i <= 4) { 
      return item;
    }
  })
}
```

And then create a new `ul` which gets the rest accordingly

To avoid having to rely on the index from the template (`let i = index+1`) you could as well just also use a function so the index stays consistent:

```
public function getFirstFour() {
  return this.footerExtraPages.map((item, i) => {
    if (i <= 4) { 
      return { index: index + 1, ...item};
    }
  })
}

public function getRest() {
  return this.footerExtraPages.map((item, i) => {
    if (i > 4) { 
      return { index: index + 1, ...item};
    }
  })
}
```

be aware that if the item object has an id attached to it, the above code could cause errors, if you remove the spread operator you would be able to retain both but would also mean you would have to remodel the template to go a level deeper.